# Can not access the attribute or the iframe which is inside iframe #document puppeteer

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer

```
  const attr = await page.$$eval("body > iframe", el => el.map(x => x.getAttribute("style")));

  console.log(attr);
```

I am trying to extract the attribute name in the second iframe which is under #doument.

When I do a copy selector it gave me the selector `body > iframe` and it is not letting me extract the attribute of the iframe. I need the name attribute and it is not letting me get it no matter what selector I use

[![click here for the image ][1]][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf2FO.png

Answer (score 0):

Edit (If you don't have an id then you can get it with the name)
Put your iframe in a variable like this:

```
var MyIframe = document.getElementsByName('iframe_id_here');
```

then you go like this to get stuff inside the iframe because it will be in an array since getelemetsByName is plural:

```
MyIframe[0].getElementById('SomeID').style.SomeProperties = 'Some_Value';
```

Should work like that.

Comment: Unfortunately, my iframe does not have  iframe id, It is within an iframe and when I right-click and copy the selector it gives me body > iframe which gives no return or incorrect return. I am trying to access the attribute which is highlighted in the above image   I will highly appreciate if you take a look at the image once and share me what can be done in this case

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should work like this. I didn't knew your iframe had no id you should probably give it an id when you create it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it, If possible can you give a look at the image and let me know exactly what I need to pass as I am new to this and not able to identify the selectors properly, The name of the webpage is variable and keep on changing  my goal is to extract the name attribute from the iframe which is within another iframe, The highlighted part is the thing which I want to extract

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend using the puppeteer recorder extension. You can record mouseclicks for example inside of the iFrame, it will then produce a script for you which you can use to get a better understanding of how to access the contents of the frame. This helped me A LOT with stuff like pop-ups, iFrames, etc...

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/puppeteer-recorder/djeegiggegleadkkbgopoonhjimgehda?hl=en

Have you tried using something like

```
let frames = await page.frames()
const frame = frames.find(f => f.url().startsWith('https://www.urlofiframe.com'))
```

or just console logging the frames variable and seeing what u can get from there?

Comment: I tried that however it is not giving me any returns, I am trying to get the attribute `name` of the iframe which is inside the iframe. I would really appreciate if you take a look at the image above and guide me what can be done